# Multiple Column REGEX search in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to search multiple columns in my Db using a regex. It works but using many and/or statments. I was wondering if it was possible to use something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM table REGEXP 'regex' IN (col1, col2, col3,.....)
```

This doesn't work, it was a guess at the syntax because I can't find anything similar by searching online. Is this a stupid idea or am I missing something very simple?

Comment: I think correct key word is REGEXP not REGEX

Comment: Fulltext search it is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to `regexp` search a value in multiple columns then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table where CONCAT(col1, col2, col3) REGEXP 'search-pattern';
```

Comment: OK, any idea of performance implications of using CONCAT()? isn't it a great deal slower? not an issue in this case but I'm here to learn!

Comment: Performance will depend upon how many columns are you trying to concat. Besides this is like finding a needle in haystack. So speed will vary a lot depending upon size of haystack. IMO this is still better than writing 10 conditions with OR if you have 10 columns to search for.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for MySQL REGEX comparison is

```
expr REGEXP pattern_string
```

You cannot use it with `IN`.  You would have to do:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE
col1 REGEXP 'regex'
OR col2 REGEXP 'regex'
OR col3 REGEXP 'regex'
```

You could also use `RLIKE` -- they are synonyms.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was doing It was just an idea!